# What are some security measures for an AJAX upvote/downvote with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, security

I'm implementing an upvote/downvote system with  the `act_as_votable` gem (https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). I think I have the controllers and models figured out, but I have a few concerns related to the AJAX parts.

Users will only be able to vote if they are logged in. I am thinking of POSTing the requests to a controller where it processes the upvote/downvote and returns a json response. The site is going to be sort of like reddit where you have lots of links with voting capabilities on a given page, so I was a little worried. I'm not really sure what I need to be worried about in terms of security and integrity, what are somethings I need to be checking for or be aware of? For example, CSRF token with AJAX calls, etc..